# Are "respins" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I came across [Ubuntu 18.04 (respin) installer crashes on Dell XPS 15 9560](https://askubuntu.com/q/1142881/248158).

It deals with a respin of Ubuntu 18.04:

> Collection of scripts and tweaks to adapt Ubuntu and Linux Mint ISO images to let them run smooth on Dell XPS 15 9560. This might work on other Dell XPS too.

From the [GitHub link](https://github.com/stockmind/dell-xps-9560-ubuntu-respin).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see how this would be on topic. We only support official Ubuntu flavors, and this isn't one. The problem described seems to be an issue with the modified installer so I closed the question and suggested to the OP that they open an issue on the respin's github page instead.